# How to use usb tethering only for guest vm and not for host system?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, tethering

I have a host system with win7 and a ubuntu guest vm. I work with virtualbox. I want to use my mobile phone with usb tethering to have access to the internet in my vm. This is not a problem, currently I just use a network bridge and I can share my mobile phones connection in the vm.

The problem is that my host system is already connected to another network and now, there is a second network avaiable. Several settings aren't working anymore, because the system is confused about those two internet connections.

How is it possible to use the tethered internet connection only for my vm? Is there a way to tell my host not to use this connection but still use it in my vm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox has USB filter functionality, using which you can pass your chosen USB device to be seen only by guest, and not by host.

So you can pass your mobile phone to guest vm and use tethering only there.

Note that you can configure USB filters for all guests, but you can actively pass the device only to single vm.

And note that USB filter functionality needs VirtualBox Extension Pack, which is free for personal use, but paid for company use.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted :) sometimes it's so easy, you just don't see the solution! Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide short description how did you managed to do it? I am trying to pull this off on Windows 10, but no luck. I set up the USB filter, but I can't see adapter in guest (not on host either)

Comment: Fixed. I didn't have VirtualBox Extension Pack (althougth I think I installed it with Virtual Box). Works like a charm now.